# Purpose of Various JS file Inside Ember Package

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

I have pulled ember with bower and I see various files. I do understand that I will have to add `ember.min.js` and `ember-template-compiler.js` to start working with ember. But I see other files that I am curious of:

```
ember 
  | - ember.debug.js
  | - ember.prod.js
  | - ember.testing.js
```

Can anyone describe purpose of these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `ember.debug.js` is the development version of ember that suplies you with many asserts and descriptive error messages and testing hooks.
- `ember.prod.js` is the un minified version of `ember.min.js`
- `ember-testing.js` is the testing framework that comes with ember.

I advice you to use `ember-cli` it will deal with setting up your entire development environment.